# Getting an object property defined in a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just defined object and it's property inside a function:

```
function objectDefinition() {
      const object = {
            property: value
      }
}
```

How can I get it from outside the function? Would something like the code below work?

```
object = {}

function objectDefinition() {
      const object = {
            property: value
      }
}
```

If it doesn't work, is there any other way?

Comment: Better to just create the object in the function (use `let` or `const` to declare it) and then return it from the function so the caller can use the return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return the object from the function.

```
function objectDefinition() {
  const object = {
        property: value
  }
  return object;
}

let someVar = objectDefinition();
```

Comment: Thank you! That's it

Comment: either `object` should be non const, or we may as well inline it with return; `return {property: value};`

Comment: @junvar That's just style. I assume this is a simplification of the real code, which is presumably more complex building of the object.

Comment: @HugoAlmeida Why isn't this obvious? Isn't this the normal way you get data out of functions? There's nothing special about objects in this regard.

Comment: or like: `const objectDefinition = () => ({property: ''})` same thing, the issue was not returning.